# How to use to_sentence with an AR collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have `User.all`, which returns 3 results.

How can I make it so I can render each result to something like:

```
<a href="path_to_user_foo_here">Foo</a>, <a href="path_to_user_bar_here">Bar</a>, and <a href="path_to_user_foobar_here">Foobar</a>
```

Which when rendered in the browser, will display as:

```
Foo, Bar, and Foobar
```

I know about the `to_sentence` helper. But not very sure how to execute this, since `User.all` returns 3 hash objects. I can use `.map(&:first_name)`, but how will I be able to provide the route path in the `link_to` method.

Looking for an approach that works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this. (answer updated)

**In a helper**:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  ...
  include ActionController::UrlWriter
  def generate_user_links_sentence
    links = User.all.collect do |user|
      link_to user.first_name, user_path(user)
    end
    links.to_sentence
  end
  ...
end

# Example: <%= generate_user_links_sentence %>
```

You can separate out the generation logic into your controller if you so wish, but it's difficult enough accessing route paths from a helper, let alone the controller. There may be a better way to do this in a view, but this is all I can really think of right now.

**Update**: Just in a view:

```
<%= User.all.collect{|u| link_to u.first_name, user_path(u)}.to_sentence %>
```

Comment: Might want `links.to_sentence.html_safe` if you're going to use just `<%= ... %>`.

Comment: Change of context. I'm trying to do: `<%= @comments.collect(&:user).uniq{ |u| link_to u.first_name, user_path(u) }.to_sentence %>`. I'm getting: `#<User:0x00000100c70050>`

Comment: Try `<%= @comments.collect{|c| link_to c.user.first_name, user_path(c.user) }.uniq.to_sentence %>`